# algorithmic + textcolor == something's wrong -- perhaps a missing item, and incorrect layout

Tags: color, algorithmic

I need to color part of an algorithm with \textcolor.  I have the following code using the algorithmic package:

```
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{xcolor}
...
\begin{algorithmic}    
    \FOR{$s = 1, \dots, S$}
    \textcolor{red} {
    \IF {$t<T'$} 
        \STATE do foo
    \ELSE 
        \STATE do bar
    \ENDIF
    }
    \ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
```

However this produces an error:  `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` and the indentation of the IF statement is broken:

[image]

I can eliminate the error with a `\STATE` command before the `\textcolor` command like so:

```
\begin{algorithmic}    
    \FOR{$s = 1, \dots, S$}
    \STATE \textcolor{red} {
    \IF {$t<T'$} 
        \STATE do foo
    \ELSE 
        \STATE do bar
    \ENDIF
    }
    \ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
```

But this injects an extra empty line into the algorithm:

[image]

What is the correct way to selectively color parts of an algorithm (or perhaps a subset of items in a list in general?)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `\textcolor`, which is more appropriate for short sequences of text, you could use `{\color{red} ... }`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}    
    \FOR{$s = 1, \dots, S$}
    {\color{red}
    \IF {$t<T'$} 
        \STATE do foo
    \ELSE 
        \STATE do bar
    \ENDIF
    }
    \ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```